# Change displayed items for combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, usability

I was wondering if there was a way in C# to have the selected item in a ComboBox (WinForms) appear as the middle element when possible.  I have already looked for a property or method that would allow this but did not find anything. I am using some in an application I am developing and this functionality would greatly improve the app's usability.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
By "middle element" I mean of what is displayed when the combobox is dropped down. Something like this: [image: Selected Element Becomes Middle of Dropped List]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean.

**OnFormLoad Event**: (or any button on which you want to implement the function)

```
int count = comboBox.Items.Count;    
comboBox.SelectedIndex =  count/2;  //no need of if else statements
```

(or)

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex =  comboBox.Items.Count/2;
```